# DFT for 2D image using C++ - bad result

Tags: c++, image-processing, fft, dft

I try write DFT in C++ Qt. I use version with exp function. I tried many versions and always result is the same. First DFT for rows, and next for columns. Image 400 x 400 RGB. Is it correct? If not, what is wrong?

```
using namespace std;
complex<double> *tab;
tab = new complex<double>[640000];
complex<double> i(0.0, 1.0);

for (int j = 0; j < 400; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 400; ++k) {
        complex<double> sum(0.0, 0.0);

        for (int n = 0; n < 400; ++n) {
            int t = (j * 400 + n) << 2;
            complex<double> arg = -i * ((2.0 * M_PI * k * n) / 400);
            complex<double> val(tmp[t] / 255.0, 0.0); //tmp - unsigned char, values R G B

            sum += val * exp(arg);
        }
        int t = (j * 400 + k) << 2;

        tab[t] = sum;
        tab[t + 1] = sum;
        tab[t + 2] = sum;
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < 400; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 400; ++k) {
        complex<double> sum(0.0, 0.0);

        for (int n = 0; n < 400; ++n) {
            int t = (n * 400 + j) << 2;
            complex<double> arg = -i * ((2.0 * M_PI * k * n) / 400);
            sum += tab[t] * exp(arg);
        }

        int t = (k * 400 + j) << 2;
        unsigned char p;

        p = static_cast<unsigned char>(static_cast<int>(round(abs(sum))) % 256);

        buf[t] = p;
        buf[t + 1] = p;
        buf[t + 2] = p;
    }
}

delete tab;
```

I use image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Did you scale the FFT properly?

Comment: You may already know that to acheive "optical" image FFT (produced by lens) you'll need to swap quadrants (1st with 3rd, 2nd with 4th), so the 0th (yours brightest) term lays in the middle. Also I'd advise to use logarithmic scale for viewing as generally your result looks alright however since FFT may produce a wide range of values with high ones being orders of magnitude larger than low ones.

Comment: To check your program, did you try to perform DFT then IDFT and compare the result with the input ?